# disturbed by or with

Tags: prepositions

The following question was in my test, where I had to choose the correct answer out of the options suggested.

> I was not disturbed _______ her anymore after I taught her a lesson.

Options were

1. with
2. by

I think it should be **with** because **with** is usually used for **people**, like **I disagree with you**. But the correct answer was **by**. I don't get how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She disturbs me. I am disturbed by her.

by
/bī/
preposition

1. identifying the agent performing an action.
2. used to show the person or thing that does something:
   The motorcycle was driven by a tiny bald man.
   We were amazed by what she told us.
   I'm reading some short stories (written) by Chekhov.